# Nginx Proxy Manager is running but not intercepting traffic?

Tags: nginx, ssl, raspberry-pi

How do I get Nginx Proxy Manger to intercept/manage traffic?

I'm trying to follow along with these tutorials, https://www.wundertech.net/how-to-self-host-bitwarden-on-a-raspberry-pi and https://www.wundertech.net/nginx-proxy-manager-raspberry-pi-install-instructions/ Everything seems to be working other than the Nginx/SSL stuff. Nginx Proxy Manager is installed and running, and I'm able to go to mything.duckdns.org and it brings me to the Bitwarden login screen, but I'm unable to get an SSL certificate.

When I try to request a new SSL certificate through the "New Proxy Host" dialog I get "Internal Error" in response. When I try to go through the "Add SSL Certificate" dialog I get

`mything.duckdns.org: There is a server found at this domain but it does not seem to be Nginx Proxy Manager. Please make sure your domain points to the IP where your NPM instance is running.`

Also, the Nginx Proxy Manger dashboard shows "0 Proxy Hosts" but when I click on it it shows the one that I've set up, and it doesn't seem to matter what I put for the Forwarding Port, random numbers still work.

I've tried rebooting the raspberry pi, and disabling and enabling the Proxy Host.

Thanks!